# Plain JavaScript: Getting children of body returns undefined

Tags: javascript, html, children

I'm trying to get all child elements of the `<body>` element, but it's not working. For some reason, it always returns undefined.

I have found similar questions on StackOverflow, but all of them have much longer code. I'm hoping that this simple question can get a simple answer.

JSFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/mkeacdsw/10

HTML:

```html
<body>
<div>
</div>
</body>
```

JavaScript:

```js
console.log("Below here");
console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("body"));
console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("body").children);
console.log("Above here");
```

If you open the browser console, you will see this:

[image: undefined console output]

As you can see, it successfully gets the `<body>` element, but not its children.

What in the world is going on? How do I get all of the children of `<body>`? I already tried replacing `children` with `childNodes` and it still doesn't work.

Comment: `document.body.children` should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.getElementsByTagName` returns a collection, not a DOM Element, which is where the children attribute resides.

You want

```
console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].children);
```

Answer (score 2):

`childNodes` not children.

```js
console.log("Below here");
document.querySelector('body').childNodes.forEach(n => {
  console.log(n);
});
console.log("Above here");
```

```html
<body>
<div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `document.body` instead:

```js
console.log("Below here");
console.log(document.body);
console.log(document.body.children);
console.log("Above here");
```

```html
<div></div>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
```

Comment: Thanks very much, this is the solution I went with in my code, but just FYI I selected the other person's answer as the answer because it's a more generic solution to the problem.

Comment: @AaronFranke glad you found it helpful